# Data Guard Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, disaster-recovery, dataguard

I want to do the disaster recovery in oracle 11g using data guard. But I don't the procedure or the way how to do it. I want all of someone that show me the document or the way to do it.

Can anyone help me to do that?

Thanks,
Ung Sopolin

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the [Data Guard Concepts and Administration](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28294/toc.htm) guide which covers the overall mechanism of Data Guard and the way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link to a data guard installation in oracle 9i. Besides some new feautures on 10g and 11g is should in essence be the same.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/DataGuard.php

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below links for Step by Step Guide

1. Step by Step Guide on Creating Physical Standby Using RMAN DUPLICATE…FROM ACTIVE DATABASE [ID 1075908.1]
2. https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/data-guard-setup-11gr2
3. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/create_ps.htm#SBYDB4722

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.